# Как использовать tornado с асинхронными функциями из python3.5 (если возможно)?

Tags: python, python-3.5, tornado

Собственно, прихожу к завершению запиливания сервиса, который, фактически - получает тексты от 1 сервиса, обрабатывает вторым и сохраняет результаты в БД.
Соответсвенно - раз большую часть времени оно должно ждать ответа от других сервисов - приюзал асинхронщину (в python3.5 введены async/await).

Теперь надо нацепить к этому вебморду (1 тип непараметризованных запросов, 1 - параметризованный). Думаю приюзать tornado. Начал с простого :

```
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.platform.asyncio import AsyncIOMainLoop
from tornado.web import Application, RequestHandler, asynchronous
from asyncio import sleep


class Handler(RequestHandler):
    async def get(self):
        print("Started")
        await sleep(10)
        self.write("Hello, world!")
        self.finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    HTTPServer(Application(
        [('/', Handler,)]
    )).listen(8888)
    AsyncIOMainLoop.instance().start()
```

Соответветственно - делаю 2 запроса на 127.0.0.1:8888/ с интервалом менее 20 секунд, выполнение обоих - начинается, но ответ я не получаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой вариант работает. Похоже, в моём случае - была проблема с инициализацией event loop-в.

```
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.platform.asyncio import AsyncIOMainLoop
from tornado.web import Application, RequestHandler, asynchronous
from asyncio import sleep, get_event_loop


class Handler(RequestHandler):
    async def get(self):
        print(0)
        await sleep(10)
        print(1)
        self.write("Hello, world!")
        self.finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    AsyncIOMainLoop().install()
    HTTPServer(Application(
        [('/', Handler,)]
    )).listen(8888)
    get_event_loop().run_forever()
```